# additional paths with azure web app returns error

Tags: azure, reactjs, azure-web-app-service, create-react-app

I made a react app using create-react-app. I am trying to deploy it on azure web app. I created a build and deployed using FTP.

When there is the internal redirect from the react the app I am able to see the webpage. But when I try to directly go to the url, I get this error.

[image: error image]

**For example:**

if base url is  www.example.com, and the app internally redirects to /new, the page goes to www.example.com/new. But if I directly try to load www.example.com/new, I get the above shown response. This doesn't happen in local testing

**Demo:**
I have created a demo [here](http://data-trigger-mass-test.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: any updates? do you find and fix the issue?

Comment: I built an react app using create-react-app and for deployment I am using [ftp deployment in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy#a-nameftpadeploy-manually-by-uploading-files-with-ftp) but I am not able see how to solve mapping additional routes in FTP deployment

Answer (score 16):

For it to work for me, I added a `web.config`-file in the public-folder (this is where `favicon.ico`, `index.html` & `manifest.json` is located), and added the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope this might help :)

Answer (score 7):

Place the below `web.config` file under the `/site/wwwroot` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this not work for me for sub url like: /some_url

Answer (score 0):

> When there is the internal redirect from the react the app I am able to see the webpage. But when I try to directly go to the url, I get this error.
>
> `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

If you use Network tool to capture network traffic when you click the button **New** to render (redirect to) the new page, you will find it just changes the URL locally instead of really requesting for  `http://data-trigger-mass-test.azurewebsites.net/new` to the server. When you directly browse and request for  `http://data-trigger-mass-test.azurewebsites.net/new` to the server, the server could not find the resource, so it returns (404) error. In order to make the URL  `http://data-trigger-mass-test.azurewebsites.net/new` work on both server and client-side, you may need to set up routes for it on both server and client side.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) discussed about “React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually”, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should always send the root html file for all client request, so that it can pass routing to react.

If the server is NodeJs, add something like below into your server.js.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" 
         />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
       </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I created a web.config file in the public-folder where the index.html is located and added the above code.

Answer (score 0):

**HashRouter** instead of **BrowserRouter** in **routers.tsx** file.

I use

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

instead of

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

That works for me. But this is a temporary solution for me.
I need to investigate more with the below solution.

I tried lots of times with the below code that does not work for me. But I see lots of people's code work with this solution.

Create a `web.config` file in the root directory where the `index.html` is located and `paste` the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```